# How to use multiple arguments in an if statement with Liquid

Tags: if-statement, jekyll, liquid

I want to use an `if` statement in Liquid with multiple conditionals. Something like:

```
{% if (include.featured == "true" and product.featured == "true") or (include.featured == "false" and product.featured == "false") %}
```

Multiple conditionals don't seem to work. Have I got the syntax wrong or can Liquid not handle this sort of if statement?

Comment: In your particular example you can just use `{% if include.featured == product.featured %}`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Unfortunately, Liquid has a poor implementation of boolean algebra.

Using Liquid's [operators](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/operators) and [tags](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/logic), here is a dirty way to achieve it:

```
{% if include.featured == true and product.featured == true %}
      {% assign test = true %}
{% endif %}

{% if include.featured == false and product.featured == false %}
      {% assign test = true %}
{% endif %}

{% if test %}
      Yepeeee!
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You could also use an if/elsif to keep everything together.

Comment: '||' becomes 'or' too :~)

Answer (score 11):

Another way you can condense this is to combine else if statements, and booleans don't necessarily need the "==" when evaluating true:

```
{% if include.featured and product.featured %}
      {% assign test = true %}
{% elsif include.featured == false and product.featured == false %}
      {% assign test = false %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: elseif is spelled elsif  for jekyll - otherwise this was helpful to me.