# Shopify Liquid: If Statement

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to enable a div class based on when a user views certain web page eg: blog, index or ../page/webpage

The code is like this:

```
{% unless template contains "index" and settings.slideshow_enabled %}
   <div class="container main content">
{% endunless %}
```

That "container main content" shows an image behind the nav bar. On other pages, the image starts from below the nav bar. A clear example here: http://retina-theme.myshopify.com/

I want to have that same homepage, link the link above, on selected pages or template:

```
{% if template == "index" and template == "page" and settings.slideshow_enabled %}
   <div class="container main content">
{% endif %}
```

So far nothing I have tried worked. Any tips?

Edited:

I can't answer my own question as yet but this worked with a tweak to the javascript:

```
{% unless template contains "page" or template contains "index" and settings.slideshow_enabled %} 
 <div class="container main content"> 
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: `template` can't equal both index and page at the same time.

Comment: @Sylar Maybe `or` and a couple of brackets will help here.

Comment: @Anton can you explain?

Comment: Did you try: {% if template == "index" or template == "page" and settings.slideshow_enabled %}
   <div class="container main content">
{% endif %}

Comment: Yes I have. It works with unless statement only for some reason. See my last comment below the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple conditions in if statements don't work so well in liquid. [See a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054564/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-in-an-if-statement-with-liquid).

One option is to use nested if statements:

```
{% if template == "index" or template == "page" %}
  {% if settings.slideshow_enabled %}
    <div class="container main content">...</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Or something like this:

```
{% if template == "index" or template == "page" %}
  {% assign correct_template = true %}
{% endif %}
{% if correct_template and settings.slideshow_enabled %}
  <div class="container main content">...</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: hi. This partially works for me:

  {% unless template contains "page" or template contains "index" and settings.slideshow_enabled %}
    
        <div class="container main content"> 
      {% endunless %}

Comment: But this controls the static header:

 var $header = $(".index .header");
  {% if settings.use_logo_home %}
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
      $('.logo img', $header).attr('src', $('.logo img').data('src-home'));
    }
  {% endif %}

I need to add ".page" to it but I dont know javascript.

Comment: @Sylar Just to check I understand your question, you want to show `<div class="container main content">` on "index" and "page" templates if `settings.slideshow_enabled`? Or do you want to show that div for templates other than "index" and "page"? (In which case you could use `unless`)

Comment: If I have more than 3 statement in the `if` condition, should I always use at most 2 statements at once and nest them up?