# Filter out collection name from product tag list (display) shopify

Tags: shopify

I would love to know how to remove from display tags that are used to automatically create collections (they appear in other product section).
For example:

> $125 
>    COLLECTION : BUSINESS
>    TAGS: AUTUMN BUSINESS BLACK

So that BUSINESS tag (which is used to form a BUSINESS collection ) is filtered out.

Tries the following 'straightforward' solution:

```
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
        {% unless tag == 'Business' or tag == 'Vintage' or tag ==  or tag == 'Boho' %}
            display {{ tag }} link
        {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Which did not see to Work
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes multiple conditions in if statements don't work so well in liquid. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471743/1367622) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23081522/1367622).)

You could try something like this instead:

```
{% assign excluded_tags = "Business,Vintage,Boho" | split: "," %}

{% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% unless excluded_tags contains tag %}
    {{ tag }}
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**

I just tested your code again, and even with the typo `or tag == or...`, it still works fine for me (just a warning on save).

Another suggestion is perhaps it's got to do with capitalisation. E.g. If you have a tag BUSINESS, then `tag == 'Business'` is not going to work. The capitalisation needs to be consistent.

**EDIT 2:**

From comment below:

> I was thinking how to automatically populate excluded tags by the names of the collections of a product.

You can use [`map`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters#map) to get an array of collection titles:

```
{% assign excluded_tags = product.collections | map: 'title' %}
```

Comment: I find it surprising as I use this kind of multiple conditions for "if" and "unless" and it works flawlessly for me.

Comment: @HymnZ It's more common when combining `or` and `and` in the same if statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works fine. I was thinking how to automatically populate excluded tags by the names of the collections of a product. "Collection: {% for collection in product.collections %}
 <a href="{{collection.url}}">{{ collection.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}" . This  is how I display collection names to which product belong (may be multiple for one product). So how do I put them in an array of excluded tags?

Comment: @jewels Please don't use `{% for collection in product.collections %}` ever. This will override the default collection value of the product for that page. Always use something else, like `c_collection` etc, instead of `collection`. For your excluded tags, your question tells me that you want to exclude tags of current collection. In that case wrap `<a ... /a>` inside `{% unless c_collection.handle == collection.handle %} .... {% endunless %}`. This way you don't need to specifically add any excluded tags

Comment: @StephSharp I agree with that. `or` and `and` in conjunction never work. I use nested conditions instead.

Comment: @jewels See my edit above, you can use map to get an array of collection titles.

Answer (score 0):

Your straightforward is incomplete.

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
{% unless tag == 'Business' or tag == 'Vintage' or tag == <missing_value_here> or tag == 'Boho' %}
display {{ tag }} link
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

The third condition is empty hence could be the reason it is failing.

Also as mentioned in another answer by Steph, multiple conditions may be unstable at times, if that the case try this:

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
{% unless tag == collection.title %}
display {{ tag }} link
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It will take care of any future collections as well.

P.S. This is assuming that the page where the tags are displaying contains a collection url.

Comment: Any error you're facing or is there no output from the code?

Comment: No, just outputs nothing

Comment: I'm getting the output as required. Please add this line code `<script>{% for colt in product.collections %}console.log('{{colt.title}}');{% endfor %}{% for tag in product.tags %}{% unless tag == collection.title %}console.log('{{ tag }}');{% endunless %}{% endfor %}</script>` in `product.liquid` and let me know the console output you see.