# Shopify Liquid Template - OR operator not working

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to achieve something quite simple.

My code is the following:

```
{% if template != 'index' or template != 'page.jump' %}
```

I then want to do something if the template isn't equal to those two pages.

However, it doesn't seem to be interpreting anything after `or`

Either of these work individually, and I've had to resort to nesting if statements which is nasty.

Is there any reason why `template` won't work with the `or` operator in a liquid template?

Comment: old question I know, but for future searchers: the problem isn't with liquid, it's with your logic -- if you want to do something if the template isn't equal to either of those pages, then `or` is not the right operator here (which is why `and` works below). once you hit `!= 'index' you evaluate to true. so you just had a fundamental misunderstanding of boolean logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the "and" operator.

```
{% if template != "index" and template != "page.jump" %}
```

There seems to be another way around here:
[How to use multiple arguments in an if statement with Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054564/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-in-an-if-statement-with-liquid)

Comment: This works perfectly. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Strange how the or operator doesn't work here though. Thanks

Comment: XOR (exclusive OR) only works (returns true) if one of the statement is true but not both at the same time. That's why you have to use 'and'.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or. Please mark as accepted answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

For the liquid it works perfectly in 2 conditions:

1. Don't use double quotes, just single quotes
2. Don't start your statement with "Not Equal" **!=**
   You can use **!=** as the second part of your statement

Example:

```
{% if product.type == 'Bundle' and product.type != 'Dress'%}
```