# Shopify STEP function in liquid loop ? Shopify iteration with STEP

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Im working in Liquid with a shopify template for the first time and I cant find any documentation on the Liquid loop function for a step object ?

```
            {% for i in (2..40)  %}                 
              <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
```

I simply want to step 2 but have tried a ruby 2.step(40,2) and java and other forms to no avail?
Has anyone found this? or is there a modulo check I can use?

PS. I just tried

```
    {% if i | modulo:2 == 0 %}
```

But this threw an error, can't find documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that Liquid is a templating language, not a programming language. There are a lot of limitations to the amount of programming logic that you do inside the liquid tags.

The for loop has [a few different options](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/iteration-tags#for), but `step` is not one of them.  If you want to iterate through the integers `2, 4, 6... 20` the only way I can think to do that is to iterate through the values `1 ... 10` and use `{% assign val = forloop.index | times: 2 %}` inside the loop to get the values that you want.

Similarly, you are not able to perform any operations within an `if` or `unless` tag.  You are only allowed to make one or more comparisons, connected with either `and` or `or` keywords.  [You cannot even use parentheses or brackets inside your `if` or `unless` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054564/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-in-an-if-statement-with-liquid) to group your logic.  (Parentheses are legal characters, but they're simply ignored)  Instead, you will need to `assign` the value to a variable, then use that variable to make your comparison.

Comment: Thanks Dave, good to know the limitations ! 

Appreciate the concept of multiplying the index of the loop to achieve.